# How can I pass request body for sklearn model, decision tree classifier in AWS Sagemaker while invoking endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I am trying to invoke a multi-model endpoint in AWS Sagemaker and I am getting a ModelError -**ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Iris-virginica'"**. I have used Sklearn model with IRIS dataset and Decision Tree Algorithm to predict the output.

```
import boto3
import json

runtime_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
content_type = "application/json"
request_body = {"Input": [[1.2,0.5, 1.7, 2.6, 2.7,1.0]]}
data = json.loads(json.dumps(request_body))
payload = json.dumps(data)
endpoint_name = "sklearn-endpoint"
print("payload ",type(payload))
response = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    ContentType=content_type,
    TargetModel="iris.tar.gz",
    Body=payload)
```

Comment: Can you try putting the floats in your vector in quotes so they are passed to the endpoint as strings?

Comment: Can you please elaborate may be with an example?

Comment: Try changing - `request_body = {"Input": [[1.2,0.5, 1.7, 2.6, 2.7,1.0]]}` to `request_body = {"Input": [['1.2','0.5', '1.7', '2.6', '2.7','1.0']]}`